# Chrome SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs setting override using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain

The Chrome dev team apparently just rolled out a new "feature" called SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs, which makes it so alert+confirm boxes from an iFrame on a different domain than the parent does not show up, by default: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576

This means if you have an embedded form, and you relied upon the standard JavaScript alert to inform the user of errors (or a confirm to ensure they want to make a change), it now does nothing, completely destroying the UX.

Obviously we can overwrite the built-in alert and confirms with custom ones, but moving away from what is built into the browser now introduces re-designs for every UI (mobile, tablet, laptop, desktop, etc.) instead of just relying upon proven, built-in technology.

**Is there a way to change this cross-domain setting, or to whitelist specific domains to override this feature?**  We do have access to the parent site with an external JS include file (obviously, otherwise this would be a wide-open back door).

Comment: Affecting Salesforce.com users too:  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BRMXQA4 They have a workaround provided where you launch Chrome with a command line flag to disable this new feature. --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"

Comment: I want to point out:  Google Chrome is running a so-called "[origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/origin-trials/)" on the behavior change highlighted here.  It's called "[Disable Different Origin Subframe Dialog Suppression](https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/2541156089743802369)".  Anyone concerned about this behavior change can register for the origin trial and give feedback.

Comment: I read the terms of the reverse origin trial and there is one that's a bit concerning. It says  "I understand that I may need to limit use of this experimental feature to some subset of my users because of the limit whereby an experimental feature will be disabled if it is used on more than 0.5% of Chrome page loads (as a median over a 14 day period)."

Answer (score 7):

To Disable SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs , which block js Dialog box pop up

**If you are single users ( Windows ) :**

1. Right click on desktop and create a shortcut
2. Windows will pop up a screen and ask you "type the location of the item:"....now paste those value into the textbox

   **"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs**
3. Click "next" then "finish" button to create the shortcut
4. Now you shall see a chrome shortcut created in your desktop .Close all active Chrome instance ( if exists ) then launch the shortcut and you will found Js pop up wont block anymore.

**Tips** :
If you want push this fix to all your cooperate domain users , you may consider use [Domain group policy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ9WNKzmiME) to update Chrome shortcut value or use custom domain logon script logic to do so

Answer (score 2):

I found a setting in the latest Chrome GPO template that creates a reg entry that will deal with this and the same reg entry placed in the Edge location also resolves the error there. (at least it worked for the problem that came up for us yesterday FWIW)

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeDialogs"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeDialogs"=dword:00000000

The latest Edge GPO templates do not have the setting yet, but I imagine it's only a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

Today I tried it again with Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 and it suddenly worked again. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Yes it works but according to this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1065085#c41 its only for two weeks

Comment: Another update: in [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1065085#c72) a project member said the deprecation got postponed until January 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Add for Mac users.

If you use mac OS:

1. Quit all running instances of Chrome.
2. Run the terminal application.
3. In the terminal, run the command:
   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"

You can see more details here :

[https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-[%E2%80%A6]oss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-%5B%E2%80%A6%5Doss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX)