# alert() is suddenly stop working on google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Suddenly the alert() is not showing up anymore in apps script. This html code is working fine if i tried it in any html editor. The alert() will pop up normally but when run from apps script, the alert() is just not showing anything.

I didn't see anything wrong with the html. I tried to refresh and restart browser or restart my computer but it still happening.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UPLOAD2');
}
```

**UPLOAD2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert("SHOW ME");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript dialogs alert(), confirm() and prompt() in cross origin iframe does not work any longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492434/javascript-dialogs-alert-confirm-and-prompt-in-cross-origin-iframe-does-n)

Comment: I'm not sure, i will do further research now. That was the post from 8 days go and the fact is it's still working  couple hours ago. I've been playing with it since morning and suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/195034108) report on Google's Issue Tracker:

> ...this seems to be intended behavior as what you are describing is related to [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576) update here.

So this seems to be know, possibly intended behaviour due to the new cross-origin iframe policy in Chrome.