# What can I use instead of Prompt after Google Chrome decided to deprecate it?

Tags: google-chrome, react-router, alert, prompt, confirm

Not long ago Google Chrome announced the soon to come deprecation of alert(), confirm(), and prompt for cross-origin iframes. [Source](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576#details)

The deprecation has been postponed multiple times due to the negative outburst of the web dev community. According to this [Chromium thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1065085) the changes won't take effected until after January 2022. However, lots of us are looking for alternatives to meet the uncertain deadline. In my case I need to substitute react-routers' own Prompt  component.

According to the RRPrompt [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt):

*The Prompt component is used to prompt the user before navigating away from a page. When your application enters a state that should prevent the user from navigating away (like a form is half-filled out), render a Prompt component.*

My example:

```
function NavigationWarningImpl({ enabled, message }: Props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (enabled && Platform.OS === 'web') {
      const listener = (event: any) => {
        // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
        event.preventDefault()
        // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
        event.returnValue = ''
      }

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', listener)

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', listener)
      }
    }
  }, [enabled])

  return <Prompt when={enabled} message={message} />
}
```

I need a solution that intercepts the navigation until the user takes action. If you are unfamiliar with React but know vanilla JS, I am also curious about solutions that would substitute blocker dialogs (not just the react-router version but in general).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492434/javascript-dialogs-alert-confirm-and-prompt-in-cross-origin-iframe-does-n/68556683#comment121204776_68556683